# get rid of rebooting messages and watchdog

Tags: reboot, kernel-parameters, watchdog

```
Broadcast message from username@Desktop (Sun 1919-08-10 11:45:14 CST):

The system is going to reboot NOW!

[756.345947] watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
[756.472889] watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
```

Every time I reboot and found a message like this.

Is there any way to get rid of these messages?

I used to have a `/etc/modprobe.d/watchdog.conf` and blacklisted:

```
blacklist iTCO_wdtblacklist 
blacklist iTCO_vendor_support
```

but now it does not work

```
[firestar@ThinkPad ~]$ inxi -b
System:
  Host: ThinkPad Kernel: 5.18.10-1-MANJARO arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.24.5 Distro: Manjaro Linux
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20WKA000CD v: ThinkPad X13 Gen 2i
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20WKA000CD v: SDK0L77769 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: N35ET47W (1.47 )
    date: 05/13/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 54.7 Wh (100.0%) condition: 54.7/54.7 Wh (100.0%)
CPU:
  Info: quad core 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 [MT MCP] speed (MHz):
    avg: 897 min/max: 400/4700
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: IMC Networks Integrated RGB Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    gpu: i915 resolution: 2560x1600~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.1.3
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V driver: e1000e
  Device-2: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz driver: iwlwifi
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 29.01 GiB (3.0%)
Info:
  Processes: 221 Uptime: 10m Memory: 15.35 GiB used: 2.68 GiB (17.5%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.19
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid them by disabling watchdog. Blacklisting is not enough, you need to add these two kernel parametres at boot time:
`nowatchdog nmi_watchdog=0`

If you use `grub` boot loader (most probably) add this line on
`/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nowatchdog nmi_watchdog=0"
```

If the line already exists add the two parametres.

After that execute:
(for Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu)
`sudo update-grub2`
(others)
`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /{path of grub.cfg file}`

You don't need watchdog for everyday use, no need to worry disabling it.

If disabling broadcast messages is what you need, you can also add `loglevel=3` (or lower, not recommended) το `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. It doesn't disable broadcasting, but fewer messages are shown on console.

Comment: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet console=tty3 nowatchdog nmi_watchdog=0 loglevel=3 udev.log_priority=3"` doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error produced? Try each parameter one by one, to see which one is the problematic. No need to change `/etc/default/grub` each time, you can edit the line at boot time, grub gives you the ability.